# Não consigo pegar os parametros de rota no angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

Toda vez que tento pegar os parametros de uma rota recebo um objeto vazio

`component`:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                this.token = params
                console.log(this.token)
            }
        )
}
```

`routing-module`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: 'recuperar-senha/:token',
        component: RedefinirSenhaComponent
    }
]
```

o resultado do log do component sempre é um objeto vazio e minha maior duvida é, isso pode estar sendo causado pela autenticação de rota?

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta:

```
const token = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.token;
```

Não esquecer de colocar no **constructor**

```
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
```